# Importing a CSV File that contains more than one value in a field

Tags: c#, csv, data-import

**Here's the data I'm trying to import from a CSV**

```
Time|Person|Products|Address

(now)|person1|val1*val2*val3|adr1
```

where `*` is a linebreak/carriage return

**here's what it looks like when I import it:**

```
(now)|person1|val1val2val3|adr1
```

**Here's what I need it to look like:**

```
(now)|person1|val1|adr1

(now)|person1|val2|adr1 etc.
```

I've tried: custom coding a CSV parser based mainly around `string.Spilt()`, it gave me the exact result and took forever to process. I've tried Sebastien Lorion's `CSVReader` and it gives me the exact same result, though it was markedly faster and easier to insert into my existing code. I've even tried the VB `TextFieldParser` with the exact same result.

Now, here's what I've thought about doing :

Somehow pass the field's values(I've no idea how to reference them) when I reach it to another method which returns a `List<string>` object through which I can iterate and add to a DataTable and from there do what needs doing. Remove my brain-stem with an old fork. Pace around muttering under my breath.

Here's the TextFieldParser code:

```
OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();
op.ShowDialog();
TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(new StreamReader(op.FileName));
parser.SetDelimiters(",");

while (!parser.EndOfData)
{
    contents.AddRange(parser.ReadFields());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem to me that if you have to stick with this CSV format, I would read it all in as you're doing above; but afterwards, I'd loop through your collection of data and then manually string split the products into the components that you need.

Trying to do it all in one pass is over complicating the issue.

Once you've got your separate classes you can then split the product on Carriage returns like so:

```
string[] result = input.Split(new string[] {"\n", "\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: You're right, but how do I split the values. The string lengths vary for each product so I can't do it by index, there's no pattern distinguishing one product from another so I can't use Regex?

Comment: I've updated my answer, that snippet will break a string on new lines. You can then loop through result adding a new line item copying Time,Person and Address from the current line item and adding the new product type.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the FileHelpers library. It's very fast and quite flexible. Although I think you will have to write a little bit of custom processing logic for what you want to do.